# Как можно указать папку для создания файла в Google Drive Api

Tags: php, google-drive

Вот код:

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName(uniqid().'.jpeg');
$createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
   'data' => file_get_contents('photo.jpeg');,
   'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
   'uploadType' => 'multipart'
));
```

Он работает, но файл создается не в нужной мне папке. Как я могу указать папку (к которой дал доступ этому сервисному аккаунту с обычного аккаунта) для загрузки фотографии?

Answer (score 0):

$file->setParents(['1ahzeTOXf1PU6-Q6Vz3BpmxxsJnHXEs4S']);
нашел метод.